# "I do it my way” vs. "I do it in my way"

Tags: prepositions

Which is appropriate:

> "I do it my way" or "I do it in my way"

My sentense is below:

> I can not do such a thing he did for you, but I think I can do something for you in my way.

In this case, which is better:

> "I think I can do somrthing for you **in** my way"

or:

> "I think I can do somrthing for you my way"

And if without "in" is corroect, I'd like to know the reason because I often see this phrase – for example:

> "live life in my own way"

Comment: "I think I can do something for you *in my own way*", using the same form as your example.

Answer (score 1):

They are both fine.

I would say that the form without "in" is more informal. (Frank Sinatra sang *I did it my way*, not *I did it* ***in*** *my way*.) But if you're trying to sound precise (and formal) then it's common to include "in." Still, neither is wrong.

Note, however, that if you're talking to somebody, it would be more natural to *only* say, "I can do it for you"—or even just "I can do it." You wouldn't mention "(in) my way" without a specific context for it:

> "Wow, you want me to do that for you—and do it *that* way? Look, I'll do
>   it, but I'll do it *my* way."

Bringing up doing something in your way, without such a context, would sound strange.